# Django - models - number of fields not known in advance

Tags: django, django-models

It's not about forms but about models.

Right now I have :

```
class Verse(models.Model):
code = models.CharField(
    max_length=10, verbose_name='vers',
    unique=True)  # ex : v01
# ... others fields
```

and :

```
class Hemistiche(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, verbose_name='codeHem',
        unique=True)  # ex : v01h01, v01h02

    verse = models.ForeignKey(
        Verse, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hemistiche')

    text = models.TextField(blank=False)

    # nothing else
```

As you can see, Hemistiche has only few fields.
Most of the time, Verse will have 2 hemistiches.
However, rarely, I have 3 ou 4 hemistiches in a verse.

So the question is : is there a way to include Hemistich as part of Verse, knowing that I may have 2, 3 or 4 of them, but I can't set it once for all.

Is it more clear ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the context of this, can you go into a bit more detail? Is it necessary for verses to have their own model?

Comment: Nothing is clear (for me) in this question.  You want to generate form fields dynamically (For rendering and data validation purposes) ? It's possible. Or dynamically generate Model fields ? If you dynamically generate model fields, anyway you should run makemigrations/migrate from command line interface. Because single Model in django is equal single database table (In most cases). clarify, please.

Comment: @user2896976 sorry for the previous state of the question (first time publishing here). I changed it. It is more now ? I put some code to show you.

Comment: @gachdavit sorry for the previous state of the question (first time publishing here). I changed it. It is more now ? I put some code to show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correctly understand what you want. Now I will show you little example. You have `ForeignKey` (`ManyToOne`/`OneToMany`) relationship.

## Your models.py

```
class Verse(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='vers', unique=True)  # ex : v01


class Hemistiche(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='codeHem', unique=True)  # ex : v01h01, v01h02
    verse = models.ForeignKey(Verse, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hemistiche')
    text = models.TextField(blank=False)
```

About models, `Verse` object represents side of `One` and `Hemistiche` object represents side of `Many`. You can make querying using `RelatedManager` in your case, which is subclass of `Manager`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection
def my_view(request):
    verse = Verse.objects.get(code='v01') # return verse object
    print(verse.hemistiche) # this returns RelatedManager object, and has instance methods available like, add(), create(), remove().
    verse.hemistiche.create(code='hemistiche_code', text='hemistiche text') # This will create row in Hemistiche table, with associated verse_id.
    verse.hemistiche.add(hemistiche1, hemistiche2, hemistiche3) # This will update all hemistiche row and sets associated verse_id for it.
    print(connection.queries) # this will log all queries performed in your view. Good for debugging.
    return HttpResponse('<h1>test</h1>')
```

Hope, I was helpful. Good luck.